# NotAllowedError: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document

Tags: javascript

NotAllowedError: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document.

I am trying to take a screenshot and want to paste website ctrl.vi or any where

so for that I am using clipboard api but I am getting error like

My JS code

```
function performAction() {
    const snapshotCreator = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        html2canvas(document.body, { scale: window.devicePixelRatio })
          .then((canvas) => {
            canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
              resolve(blob);
                            console.log("Message came")
              
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  };

  snapshotCreator().then((blob) => { 
 
  console.log(window.navigator.clipboard + "Clipboard");
     window.navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ 'image/png': blob })])
      .then(() => {
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Image successfully copied to clipboard';
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Bara")
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Error copying image to clipboard: ' + error;
      });
  });
}
```

For running This is my sample html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Your Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your page content goes here -->
    <div id="result">Result will be displayed here.</div>
    <button onclick="performAction()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Same I am using in here https://jsfiddle.net/u70snr8w/9/

What should I do and what is wrong with my technique.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what you should check is if you are hosting or working with localhost. Clipboard API only works with secured sites. You must have HTTPS URL to work with it.

I can suggest to try it and host using ngrok link. You will get better idea if this is the cause.

Do try and let me know how it goes. Thank you.